# Chrome spell check no longer works for last two months

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, browser

If I delete Chrome and reinstall a fresh copy, can I expect to get the spell check back? Is it a good idea to delete the old Chrome program first, then start the new exe?

Comment: yes, delete the old chrome before installing the new version

Comment: You can uninstall Chrome in Control Panel > Programs

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling your old version of Google Chrome won't (hopefully!) clear the settings in your profile.

If the spell check does not work, verify if it's activated: right-click on a textarea, select "Spellcheck" and ensure that "Check the spelling of text fields" is checked.

Also ensure you have at least one dictionary installed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of uninstalling Chrome, try the following:
1. Kill all chrome processes.
2. Open folder
"C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\".
3. Remove all *.bdic files from this folder.
4. Start Chrome to check if it fixed the problem (it should redownload these bdic files).

Answer (score 0):

Even though your user language might be set to "english" you still must add "english" to the list of "languages" (in the "settings tab') Chrome uses to perform spell check.  The same rule applies to any other language, it must be added to the list of languages